# Laravel Guzzle Request gets wrong DB Connection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I am trying to make a request from one Laravel project to another. The issue that I am getting is that the second Laravel is using the first Laravel Database Connection. So it is complaining that a table does not exist.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
$data = ['test' => 'foobar'];
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = getenv('API_BASE') . 'stock-list';

$res = $client->request('POST', $url, [
    'headers' => [
        'X-Public' => getenv('API_PUBLIC'),
        'X-Hash' => ApiService::Encrypt(getenv('API_PRIVATE'), json_encode($data)),
    ],
    'json' => $data,
    'http_errors' => false,
]);

echo "<pre>" . print_r($res->getBody()->getContents(), true) . "</pre>";
```

Has anyone ever come across something like this?

Comment: Worth mentioning that getContents will only return the remainder of the stream, if you want to safely return the whole body, you should cast it to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default db connection runtime like this:

So let's say you have

- 1 security db with credentials that is the default db design time.
- 1 or more databases containing data for 1 or more users.

You log in using the security db and based on the user change the default db to the data db.

```
    config(['database.connections.data' => array(
                'driver'    => 'sqlsrv',
                'host' => $connection['Database_Server'],
                'database' => $connection['Database_Name'],
                'username' => $connection['Database_User'],
                'password' => $connection['Database_Password']

            )]);

            DB::setDefaultConnection('data');
```

If you don't need such flexibility you can define the connection per model:

```
class A extends Model {
    protected $connection = 'security';
    protected $table = 'A';
}
```

Comment: The issue I was having was the the .env variables were being overridden when calling another Laravel project.

Comment: Ok, so your problem is solved now? Otherwise not using the .env for connection but the model instead will work!

Answer (score 7):

The way to fix this as I am running both Laravel projects on the same server, is to change the environment variable names in the .env file.

```
DB_DATABASE=XXXX
```

becomes

```
XXX_DB_DATABASE=XXXX
```

This needs to be done on one of the Laravel setups then it all works properly.

Comment: Good solution. Seems once PHP sets the environmental `DB_DATABASE` variable, it cannot be changed by the second app.